# Switch integral and differential operator

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I want to know if

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\large- \frac{x^2}{c+2t}} \, dx =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d}{dt} e^{\large- \frac{x^2}{c+2t}} \, dx $$

holds.

Therefore I have to check if

$\left| \frac{d}{dt} e^{\large- \frac{x^2}{c+2t}} \right| \leq h(x) $ holds for some integrable function $h$.

I don't find any function $h$ with this property, because I don't know how to get rid of the exponentional term that depends on $t$.

$$\left| \frac{d}{dt} e^{\large- \frac{x^2}{c+2t}} \right|  = \frac{2 x^2}{(c+2t)^2} e^{\large- \frac{x^2}{c+2t}}.$$

Any clues?

Edit: It is given that $c >0$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}_0$.

Comment: For $t$ so small that $c+2t < 0$, you integrand is not integrable. Do you assume that this is not the case? Also note, that you can assume $t \in (t_0 - \delta, t_0 + \delta)$ and only have to show $|\dots| \leq h(x)$ for $t$ from that interval.

Comment: @PhoemueX thank you. I have added an important note. I am still not able to find a majorant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $t < t_0$. Then $c + 2t < c + 2t_0$ and hence $x^2/(c+2t) \geq x^2/(c+2t_0)$ and thus $$e^{-\frac{x^2}{c+2t}} \leq e^{-\frac{x^2}{c+2t_0}}.$$

Furthermore, $$\frac{x^2}{(c+2t)^2} \leq \frac{x^2}{c^2}.$$

Putting everything together, we can majorize by

$$ \frac{x^2}{c^2} \cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{c+2t_0}},$$

which is integrable.

This shows that you can interchange integral and derivative for $t \in (0, t_0)$ for any $t_0 > 0$, i.e. for all $t > 0$.

EDIT: Keep this trick in mind! It is often sufficient to only find a majorizing function that is independent of $t$ for $t$ in a fixed subset.